# What's going on in Spring Boot OAuth2 `AbstractTokenGranter.validateGrantType()` method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm securing Spring Cloud/Spring Boot microservices with OAuth2 and all seems nicely wired up in the Authorization Server. But when I send a POST request via postman to `/oauth/token` to obtain an access token with `grant_type = client_credentials` I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Unauthorized grant type: client_credentials"
}
```

However in the `oauth_client_details` database table where OAuth Clients are registered, I have the following setup for the current Client making this request;

```
authorized_grant_types = `password, authorization_code, client_credentials, refresh_token`
```

So I took the liberty to debug Spring Boot's entire oauth flow and found something very funny happening in the `AbstractTokenGranter.validateGrantType(String grantType, ClientDetails clientDetails)` method. See the illustration below;

[image]

So I'd like to understand what may likely be going on here, cos it's practically unfathomable to me.

Comment: This seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963590/why-does-spring-boot-oauth-server-throw-unsupportedgranttypeexception-only-with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using RDBMS. When you insert client record in `oauth_client_details` table, make sure there are no spaces in value for `authorized_grant_types`column.

Value should be like this (no space after comma):

```
'password,client_credentials,refresh_token'
```

Comment: Holy Smokes!... This had me stuck for 1.5 whole days... and to think it was just cos of spaces in the comma separated list???... Argghhh!!!... Now I realize when i look into that debugger, the spaces were actually there and I didn't for my life even  notice.

Thanks @Vijay, you rock!

Comment: I feel you, I too once spent almost the entire day to figure this out. I'm glad I was able to help.